# Stopping spambots with JS(jQuery) event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, spam-prevention

Ok, so I've been looking around at some recommendations on how to prevent spam using JS and hidden fields, and sessions, and all sorts of other clever tricks, but none of them seem terribly good.

I have a potentially better way to do this, but just need someone to tell me if bots trigger jQuery events like "keypress", "focus", "blur", "etc".

I know I could probably eliminate bots if they had to trigger the "mouseover" event, but that doesn't help for mobile users.

I'm basically just looking for a list of JS event listeners that aren't triggered by spambots.

Comment: Way too broad; we don't know how every spambot out there works.

Comment: many bots don't even execute javascript. though, you can use that to your advantage.

Comment: @Daedalus Sure, not every spambot, but at least some experience with any spambots would be useful to know.

Comment: @KevinB, do you have any knowledge of what this percentage would be? 10% use it, 50%?

Comment: nope. good luck getting those kinds of numbers.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Worth a try. Sounds like I'm just going to have to test it myself and see what the results are like. Then I can post my solution, and every spambot will start using JS... ;)

Comment: I mean, the number of spambots and percentages isn't really that useful, just blanket block all spam using a wide variety of methods. honeypot, word checks, captcha if it looks fishy, throttle requests from same ip, track user interaction on page, etc.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That's probably the best answer I'm gonna get I'm guessing. I don't use Captcha, because it decreases conversion, and honeypots use excess bandwidth, so gonna stick with combo of 2 hidden fields. 1 detecting JS events, and one that checks if the bot enters text into it. Please post your previous comment as an answer, and I'll consider this answered. Thanks for your quick feedback.

Comment: *"and one that checks if the bot enters text into it"* that's a honeypot, :p

Comment: aha, thanks @KevinB, I was thinking of a different honeypot, namely the type that creates dynamic pages with tonnes of fake email addresses for bots. Robots.txt file says don't crawl, bad bot crawls, bad bot gets tonnes of bogus emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless spam bots are being programmed specifically for your page, usually you can just do:

1) An input element hidden via css (move it offscreen, or behind another element, but don't actually set visibility:hidden or display:none).  If it has a value, it's spam.

2) Create a hidden input, set it's value to the current *server* time.  When the form is submitted, see how long it took them to fill it out. Did they do it in half a second?  Probably spam.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know for the honeypot, but the server-time requires PHP on the form page, which I'd like to stay away from.

Comment: I took your advice on the honeypot, using absolute positioning to move it off the screen. Additionally, I did some jQuery stuff that listens for keypress events in inputs, as well as focus events. If there aren't any, it's a bot, or some idiot who disabled JS who I don't care about anyway.